# Column "not contained in either an aggregate function or a GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

The query:

```
SELECT 
    A.mrno, A.remarks, 
    B.itemcode, B.description, B.uom, B.quantity, 
    C.whsecode, MAX(C.quantity) AS whseqty, D.rate 
FROM 
    Mrhdr A
INNER JOIN 
    Mrdtls B ON A.mrno = B.mrno
INNER JOIN 
    inventoryTable C ON B.itemcode = C.itemcode
INNER JOIN 
    Items D ON B.itemcode = D.itemcode
WHERE 
    (A.mrno = @MRNo AND B.quantity < C.quantity);
```

The error:

> Column 'Mrhdr.mrno' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It says that the column mrno is not contained in the aggregate function of something, but when I do something about it like put it in a GROUP BY clause, the next column requests return the same error until the last column except the `C.quantity` column, and when they are all in a GROUP BY clause it will only return the same output not returning the highest or maximum value for the quantity. What should I do with the other columns when I use MAX or aggregate functions.

The output of the query above:

[image]

If I put all of the columns in a GROUP BY clause it returns an output with two of the itemcode FG 4751, it just removes the error of aggregate function, but I just want the highest value to be returned (just the 100, the highest quantity in the warehouse/inventory).

Comment: Usually, if you put some of your columns under the aggregation function then all other columns must be either under the aggregation function or listed in 'group by' clause

Comment: Please tell us what the query is supposed to do. So far it looks like you want to show all Mrdtls (order details maybe?) that have an amount smaller then the total inventory for the product. So with a product of a stock of 10 + 10 = 20 and orders 10, 15, 20, and 25, you would show the orders 10 and 15 only. Is this what you want the query to do?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Please tag the request with it. The SQL standard would probably be fine with a mere `GROUP BY b.id` while some other DBMS may require additional columns in that clause. Always tag SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I added the output it returns and the output the query supposed to do. I forgot to add it when I posted it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to deal with the maximum inventory quantity per product. But you are joining all inventory rows, where you should only pick the maximum quantity rows.

This can be done with a lateral join, if your DBMS supports this (you have forgotton to tell us which you are using) or simply by joining the rows in question by applying a window function as follows.

```
SELECT 
    A.mrno, A.remarks, 
    B.itemcode, B.description, B.uom, B.quantity, 
    C.whsecode, C.whseqty, D.rate 
FROM 
    Mrhdr A
INNER JOIN 
    Mrdtls B ON A.mrno = B.mrno
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
      itemcode, whsecode, quantity as whseqty,
      MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY itemcode) AS max_qty
    FROM inventoryTable
) C ON B.itemcode = C.itemcode AND C.whseqty = C.max_qty
INNER JOIN 
    Items D ON B.itemcode = D.itemcode
WHERE 
    A.mrno = @MRNo AND B.quantity < C.whseqty;
```

This query should work in most DBMS. If you are working with a DBMS that supports the standard SQL `FETCH WITH TIES` clause, I'd change the join to:

```
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT itemcode, whsecode, quantity as whseqty
    FROM inventoryTable
    ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itemcode ORDER BY quantity DESC)
    FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
) C ON B.itemcode = C.itemcode
```

so as to only select the top rows inside the subquery already and not to awkwardly filter them later. But well, a lateral join may even be considered more straight-forward here.

Comment: The whsecode returns an error because it is not inside the SELECT statement of C

Comment: @Richard Johnson: Thank you for pointing this out.. I missed that part. So we can't aggregate, but must pick rows instead. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to putting everything in a group by clause would be to use a window function. The question then becomes what is the MAX value relative to?

For example, you could get the MAX value based on all criteria, which would return a similar result to group by without leaving only distinct values for the column.

```
SELECT 
    A.mrno, 
    A.remarks, 
    B.itemcode, 
    B.description, 
    B.uom, 
    B.quantity, 
    C.whsecode, 
    MAX(C.quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY A.mrno, A.remarks, B.itemcode, B.description, B.uom, B.quantity, C.whsecode, D.rate) AS whseqty, 
    D.rate 
FROM 
    Mrhdr A
INNER JOIN 
    Mrdtls B ON A.mrno = B.mrno
INNER JOIN 
    inventoryTable C ON B.itemcode = C.itemcode
INNER JOIN 
    Items D ON B.itemcode = D.itemcode
WHERE 
    (A.mrno = @MRNo AND B.quantity < C.quantity);
```